# Status error 401 when running twitter using node. Possible authorization error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, twitter, authorization

I've come across a connection issue using the npm twitter API. I have been unable to resolve this issue so far. The issue I had occured while reading and practicing from a book by Semmy Purewal, in this example we want to stream tweets which contain certain words. Solving the issue I've tried various different methods which I either found online or thought of myself. I will first show the Error code from my terminal, after that I will mention what I have tried and what my setup is. Please take note that I am a complete beginner at programming, I never the less enjoyed trying to solve the problem with that I could find online. However, after finding no satisfying solution I turn to Stack Overflow to ask my first tech related question ;).

The error at running twitter.js (the JS file found at the end of the question)

```
Error: Status Code: 401
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/app/twitterapi/node_modules/twitter/lib/twitter.js:277:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Request.onRequestResponse (/home/vagrant/app/twitterapi/node_modules/request/request.js:1066:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:414:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:88:23)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:304:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
```

My js code looks exactly like the example given in the book on page 197. I have learned that the status error 401 is thrown when there are authorization issues, OR at other non-described moments (according to Twitter API).

Differences in setup:

- I have installed node packages locally in the twitter folder because I had errors installing Express. (I first ran npm init, followed by npm install express)
- I run Ubuntu 16.04
- I run virtual box 5.2 (instead of 6)
- The server is run on a vagrant box

A couple of methods I have tried:

- Using different twitter API's instead of ntwitter (such as 'twitter' and 'twit')
- Creating an object variable containing the authorization codes and used that to initialize my twitter
- Solely ran the twitter creation line (without the stream), which gave no errors.
- Used a different statement instead of statuses/filter and track :

Unfortunately I have broken my head trying to solve this for a couple of hours, I enjoyed trying to figure out what the issue is, but I will continue without using this example nor the subsequent practice exercises using this example. Never the less I would like to see if anyone could find a solution. I would love to experiment using the twitter API

Thank You!

My js and json file are followed.

```
var twitter = require("twitter"),
    credentials = require("./credentials.json"),
    client;

var credentialObject = {
"consumer_key": "xx",
"consumer_secret": "xx",
"access_token_key": "xx",
"access_token_secret": "xx"
};

console.log(credentials);

//setting up our twitter object
client = new twitter(credentials);


//setting up our twitter stream with three parameters, seperated by commas
client.stream(
    //the first parameter is a string
    "statuses/filter",

    //second parameter an object containing an array
    {"track": ["Awesome", "cool", "rad", "gnarly", "groovy"]},

    //the third parameter is our callback for when the stream is created
    function(stream){
        stream.on("data", function(tweet){
            console.log(tweet.text);
        });

         stream.on('error', function(error) {
                throw error;
        });
    }
);
```

credentials.json file structure

```
{
"consumer_key": "xx",
"consumer_secret": "xx",
"access_token_key": "xx-xx",
"access_token_secret": "xx"
}
```